# How can i create a general class to handle all inputs from an input text field

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a object called WorkflowsAndQueuesInitializerService it defines queues in a workflow and the next step it would route too given a specified call result. I have a method inherited from an interface class that's called CalculateDueDate that takes a from step instance and a next step timespan as parameters. The issue that i am having is being able to generally just override a due date given a input from a input text field with out taking a round trip across multiple class methods.  I have a mapped class called NextStep that has a constructor that takes a due date timespan as well. What i would like to achieve is in my class form instance i would just like to pass a value from the input text box and recalculate the duedate without all the hassle is there an easier way to achieve this with the information that has been given?

```
public override void CollectFormValues(IFormValuesCollection values)
    {
        this.CalculatedShipDate = TypeConverter.ToNullableDateTime(values["CalculatedShipDate"]);
    }
```

Above is a method that retrieve the form values from the HTTP POST.

This is a transient form instance, which means my application doesn't automatically commit the values of the form back to the database. Normally, `CollectFormValues()` only save the values into the object, but doesn't commit anything to the database. But because this is a transient form, this method is also responsible for saving the values back to the database.

Also I ahve a class that Retrieve an instance of the class that should be used to calculate the due date for the next StepInstance, below:

```
public static IDueDateCalculator GetDueDateCalculator( string className )
    {
        if ( String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace( className ) )
            return new DefaultDueDateCalculator();

        Assembly assembly = typeof( IDueDateCalculator ).Assembly;
        Type calcType = assembly.GetType( className );
        return (IDueDateCalculator) Activator.CreateInstance( calcType );
    }
```

Not sure what my best possible solution would be thus why i am comming here for any feedback and/or assistance. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the due date, but you want to allow it to be overridden by the user as well.

So that's fairly easy.

This is VB, but you should be able to get the idea.

```
Class Something

    Private oDueDate As Nullable(Of DateTime) = Nothing

    Private Sub CalculateDueDate
        oDueDate = {some calculation between the date and timespans}
    End Sub



    Public Property DueDate As DateTime
        Get
            If (Nothing Is oDueDate) OrElse (Not oDueDate.HasValue) Then
                CalculateDueDate
            End If
            Return oDueDate
        End Get
        Set(value as DateTime)
            oDueDate = value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```